# Mulitples Rest API entries appear yet post was deleted

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

Hoping you can help.
We have a custom post that we edited multiple times for test purposes. However, each of those occurrences were appearing as separate entries in the rest route URL. SO we deleted the single custom post. The entries still appear. SO we deleted the rows in the database. (When checking the site’s database we saw references to “understanding God” in the following tables: wp_postmeta wp_posts wp_wpfaqquestions)The entries still appear. Server object cache has been deleted – in fact the post url has been added to the exclude cache script to be sure. Still – the multiple entries appear.

When looking at the basic rss now, the entries do not appear. Something is going on and we’re stumped.

Duplicate entries “Understanding God” appear here:
https://wels.net/?rest_route=/wp/v2/faq&per_page=30&order=desc

They do not appear at all here:
https://wels.net/?feed=faqs

Can you help?
Thanks for your post.
j

Comment: wp_wpfaqquestions isn't a standard WordPress table. Is it from a plugin, and does the plugin add the /faq REST endpoint, i.e. it's the plugin's code that you need to look at? I guess something needs fixing to filter on post type returned.

Comment: True, FAQ  is a plugin. The basic RSS url looks good though. That means the plugin isnt the culprit. I was thinking instead REST API in some form is responsible.

Comment: If you try and fetch them by post ID, e.g. https://wels.net/?p=23968 then they work, so it looks to me like they do still exist in the database. No idea why the FAQ feed is excluding them though.

Comment: It was one custom post (faq) edited multiple times. SO now I've stumbled on an article/plugin delete old slugs.  There are a ton of those out there, but  none for "understanding-god". Yes, I saw those post ids as well 23964-68.

Comment: So the ?p= is referring to a shortlink (not a slug). How do you get rid of those if the actual content has been deleted?